# How can I lookup interactively the inferred type of a variable within the vscode IDE?

Tags: daml

Some IDEs allow you to inspect the inferred type of a variable (i.e. IntelliJ provides Scala types using Ctrl-Shift-P). Does the DAML IDE provide something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Ctrl-K Ctrl-I` (or `Cmd-K Cmd-I`) which is the shortcut for displaying hover information which will also include the type. At the moment, there is nothing that only shows you the type.
Take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing for more shortcuts.